# Create a Wifi hotspot that shares just a single video with those who connect (not for sharing internet connection)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, hotspot

Bit of a weird question, but I want to create a hotspot using a phone, or some specialised device (preferably not a whole computer) to broadcast a video to users at an event.

Many public wifi hotspots have a sign-in page that pops up automatically when you connect to the hotspot. I want something similar to happen, but it should pop up with a webpage that has a video embedded.

My problem would be solved if I could buy a router which has the ability to act as a public hotspot, and with an editable sign-in page (and enough memory to store a video), but I'm not sure if something like this exists, or how to go about finding one.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

**[EDIT]** Clarification: My target users are mostly smartphone users who will be walking around at the event. Ideally it would up up a webpage designed by me with an embedded video and they can click play and start watching. Oh also, the router won't have access to the internet, so all files would need to be stored on the router.

Comment: What you want is a so-called captive portal. But please clarify the nature of the video: Is it simply a file that users should be able to watch? What are the target devices? PCs? Smartphones?

Comment: Oh great, there's something made for this? I've edited the question with clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a pretty decent page on captive portals, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal.

There are wireless routers that contain a captive portal which hosts the login page, but I'm not aware of any that has sufficient storage to actually host a video. With a separate system hosting your video and a little bit of tinkering it should be doable. I think you wouldn't necessarily even need a router, just sufficient amount of Access Points to cover the area.

One way could be using a separate system to host your video. That system would host the web server and the captive portal, and provide DHCP and DNS service for the clients.

You could then create an open SSID without authentication. This allows the client to get an IP address from the DHCP server. When user then opens a browser and tries to access a website, the client will first do a DNS request. The captive portal will kick in, and redirect user to a specified url. That would normally be a login page, but I can see no reason why it couldn't be the page containing your video. If the user has set a browser homepage, redirection would happen immediately when the browser opens.

[EDIT]

There's a way to use RasPi as a hotspot, http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot. You could add the DHCP, DNS, web server and captive portal to that as well. However there is an issue the writer mentions - most USB WiFi NICs or other dongles do not have very much transmit power, which limits the reach of your hotspot. I'd use an external USB HDD to store the video to minimize wear on the SD card.

[EDIT 2]

Maybe Zeroshell (http://www.zeroshell.org/) or something similar might do the job.

Comment: Thanks so much! The RasPi implementation sounds like fun and I'll have a play around with zeroshell too.